# What type of SVG is this?

Tags: svg, svg-animate

I'm attempting to reverse engineer an SVG animation in JavaScript to better understand the animation and I'm seeing the following SVG code representing an "Up" motion in JavaScript. However the SVG itself doesn't look like any typical SVG code I am used to using. Can you help identify how this SVG is structured? Or how I can adjust the follwing code so I can open it in an image editing software?

```
d 601 9aAaAaAnBkNnUaNaN"/D 18 10bAaAnAnBuXaN"/F 22 10W7AaAaBaEaGiAW-6NiNnXaNbUaNaNaN"/D 30 10bAaEuUnU"/D 114 10bAaAnAnBuXaN"/F 117 10W7AaAaBaBaAaGkAn0NkNnKaNaNaUaNaU"/D 125 10eAaGnAnUnUnU"/D 66 12eBnAnAnNnUaN"/F 70 12W6AaAaAbEaGkAn2NuKaNaUaNaNaNaN"/D 76 12gEuNnNnN"/D 593 12eBnAnAuKaN"/F 596 12eAaAeUbAnEbKeAnAbJnAiAxNxAkAnUaXnNbNaNaU"/D 604 13bEuK"/D 166 14eEnAkKaN"/D 608 14aAnN"/F 169 15eAeAaAaBaAaAnAnBn0NkNnNnKbNgNaU"/D 222 15aAbBaGxKnKaN"/D 175 16gEnAnUnNnN"/D 308 16aAaAaAaBuAnAnEaAaAaEnAuNnNuNnUnNaUbw-7bN"/D 314 16gAaGkNuX"/D 268 17eAaAaAaAaAaGnBnNuUuUaUiNaNaU"/D 501 17bAaAuAnAnKaN"/D 548 17eAnAnAnAnKaN"/F 552 17jEW-6AkNaNaNbN"/D 557 17gExK"/D 209 18bAaEeAaBnAuAeAW8NnNnKgGnBn1NkGaAuNnNnXaUnw-6aN"/F 216 18jAaEgAxEaAaAW-8NkNbNaUnNkUaAeK"/D 260 18eAaBnAuAnEaBnAnBeAaEnAkNnXnNnNnXaNbXaNaN"/D 364 18eAaBuNkNaN"/D 509 18bAaBnAaEnAeAaAaBnAaEnAxXaNuNuNW-8AnAuUaUaNbNW6AeKnNnUaN"/D 159 19bAaBaAaAeAa0UaNaNeGnAnAnAiNn3NnNnNnXaN"/F 213 19aAnN"/D 214 19bBkNaN"/D 356 19eAnAnAnAnBbNW9NeAaAbAaAaBaBnBkBxUnNaNeUaNnUuNW-9AkAnAnEaAeAaBnAkUkNnXaNaNaw-6aNaN"/D 460 19eAaBuAnNnK"/F 502 19W6BaAaEkNW-6AuAnUaUaNaNaN"/F 312 20gAgAnAnBnAaAaEaAaNaGuAkAW-7NuNnKaAbNaKnNnNnKaNaNbN"/F 358 20W8AbAaAkAW-9AuUaNaNaN"/D 403 20eBnBnNnK"/F 407 20jAbAaAaAaGnAkAW-8NnNnUaUaUaNaN"/D 412 20gEnNnNuN"/D 451 20gAnAnAnBnI"/F 455 20jBaAaEbNaNaGuAnAn1NnXaUaNaNaN"/D 551 20W6AeAaAaAaEnNuNuNW-9AuAnKaNaNeN"/F 557 20gAaBnNnNkN"/D 17 21jAW6NjAaAaBaw6nJnBnAxNnUnNaNbNaNaKnKnNnNW-8AuAnAnGaBbAaAbAnAuAuNnNnw-7nIaUaN"/D 113 21eAa0NeAaAaBaBnEuKnNuNW-7AuAnBnBnBaAaAeBnAnAxNnw-6nNnKaKaUaU"/F 263 21W8BnBbBnNuEbNaNbAaBnNuAnEaBnAW-9NaKnNkUaNaBeUnNnAnUnKaNbN"/D 320 21ew9uAnNnKnNnNaUaNaN"/F 511 21aAnN"/D 596 21gAgNjAbBaEaBnBnJnBuAuNnNnXaNbNbNbNnNnNnNnNkNW-8AuAuKaNeN"/D 65 22aAa2NeAaBaw6uUnUnNuNW-6AkAnAnAnBuw-6aUaN"/F 462 22bAuN"/D 462 23bAaAnAuK"/F 464 23aAnN"/F 512 23aEuNaU"/F 21 24W8AaAaEaEnAnAuAW-7NnNuUnXaNaNbN"/D 417 24aAaBaAnBnAiAW-9NuNnKaNaBaAaAW8NeNaX"/F 549 24W9AbAbAaBxAnBnAW-6NuNuUnKaNbN"/F 596 24W8AeAaAaAaAaAuAuAuAnExNuNuNnNnNnKnUbNbN"/F 71 25W6AbAaBaBaAnAnAnAkAiNkNnNnNnKaNaNaNeN"/F 119 25W7AbAaEaBnAuAnAkAxNkNnNnUaUaUaNbN"/D 265 25bAuN"/F 359 25W9AbBaAnBkAnAaBuAW-7NaUnNkNnKaNaNeN"/D 403 25aAnN"/D 449 25bGaAa1NaNbNaAbJnNuNW-6AW-8NnNnNnX"/D 269 26bAaAnAuK"/D 361 26bAuN"/D 365 26bAaAnAuK"/F 161 27a3AgGnBuAkAW-6NkNnNnXnNaN"/D 262 27aAaBkUaN"/D 357 27bAaBnAuUnNaN"/F 497 27aAnN"/F 211 28eAa1GnBnNnAkAxNkNnNaNnX"/F 500 28W8AbAbAnGkAW-6NuNnNnUnNbNaN"/D 592 28aEaAaAaAbEnAkNnNnw-8"/D 158 29eGaAuNuX"/D 272 29bAaAaAnAnAuNnKaN"/D 546 29aBbAbEnAuNnNnI"/D 559 29gJnAxNnUaUaN"/F 418 30aGuAkAW-8NuKW9NjN"/F 403 31aAnN"/F 460 31W6AbAuAuAxAiNuNnUW8N"/D 65 32aAaAaAeAnAnAuNuI"/D 81 32aGnBxNnUeNaNaN"/D 129 32aEnAnAxNnNeNaNbN"/D 177 32aw6uAuNnNnUeNbU"/F 275 32aAnN"/F 274 33aAnN"/D 222 34aBnAkUeN
```

Comment: That isn't valid SVG data.

Comment: Maybe some obfuscated or custom vector format (using some library/framework). Which format is the original source?

Comment: I don't recognise this either. Check for any external animation JS library scripts the site may be loading.